# Как сделать корректный отступ слева и справа у таблицы с width=100%?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  width:10cm;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:auto;
}
.line {
  background-color:#77AAFF;
}
table {
  width:100%;
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
  margin-left:0.25cm;
  margin-right:0.25cm;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="line">Div имеет длину 100%, чётко умещается между границами</div>
  <table cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
       <td>Таблица немного сдвинута вправо, выходит за границу</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Первый способ

Обернуть таблицу в `div` и задать ему необходимый `margin`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  width:10cm;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:auto;
}
.line {
  background-color:#77AAFF;
}
.wrapper {
  margin-left:0.25cm;
  margin-right:0.25cm;
}
table {
  width:100%;
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="line">Div имеет длину 100%, чётко умещается между границами</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
         <td>Теперь таблица тоже умещается между границами и имеет необходимые отступы</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Второй способ

Использовать `calc()`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  width:10cm;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:auto;
}
.line {
  background-color:#77AAFF;
}
table {
  margin:auto;
  width:calc(100% - 0.5cm);
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="line">Div имеет длину 100%, чётко умещается между границами</div>
  <table cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
       <td>Теперь таблица тоже умещается между границами и имеет необходимые отступы</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Замени у таблицы `width:100%;` на `max-width:100%;`